# doctype affects width and height of html/body/canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, doctype

I've got a very simple HTML file with a canvas. I've implemented a resizeToWindow function so if the user resizes the browser window, the canvas resizes with it.

However, I was getting scrollbars in my window. I noticed a small white area underneath the canvas with my drawing, and when I used the element inspection tool, this area didn't seem to correspond to any of the elements (html, body, or canvas). I tried messing with window.innerHeight and innerWidth code, I tried playing with CSS, nothing... and then...

I removed the !doctype html from the top of my code and it started working beautifully.

I've tried this in: Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera, so it's not a webkit thing!

My HTML is simply the usual HTML5 head, then a body and a canvas that is initialized to 800 x 600.

CSS is:

```
html, body, canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and my resize to window:

```
function resizeToWindow() {
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

I just find it very odd that this doesn't work with the doctype, but does without. (I would expect, if anything, for it to be opposite, since these properties and this code supposedly works for standards mode in all current browsers).

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah interesting. It seems that the `<canvas>` element has, by default `display:inline`, like the `<img>` element which I suppose makes sense. This means that it is placed on the baseline of its containing block, so the white space at the bottom that you see is the gap between the baseline and the bottom of the containing block.

This only happens in full standards mode, so that's why removing the doctype removes the white space, In almost standards mode and quirks mode, the canvas element is placed at the bottom of the containing block.

The standard fixes for this resolve the problem. Use either:

```
 canvas { vertical-align:bottom; }
```

or

```
 canvas { display:block; }
```

and the white space and scrollbar will be gone.

Comment: YES! thank you :-)  Bizarre... the mystery of non-standards modes continues. I'll be glad when those days are gone.