# Html Doctype tag affects javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

I've noticed strange behavior of html/javascript.

I have this javascript code

```
window.onload = function(){

var pmap = document.getElementById('pmap'); 

var marker_sl = document.getElementById('marker_sl');
var marker_uk = document.getElementById('marker_uk');

    marker_sl.style.left = pmap.width * 70.5 / 100;
    marker_sl.style.top = pmap.height * 48 / 100;

    marker_uk.style.left = pmap.width * 44 / 100;
    marker_uk.style.top = pmap.height * 14.5 / 100;   
};
```

it doesn't work when I add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

or

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

tags. Otherwise It works as expected.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266276/doctype-affects-width-and-height-of-html-body-canvas) in stackoverflow. But it doesn't seem to help.

Why this happens. Can you please tell me.

Well, Here goes my entire HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

<body>
<article>
<img src="images/price_map.jpg" id="pmap" />
<a href="#" id="marker_sl" style="position:absolute;display:block;"><img src="images/marker.png"  /></a>
<a href="#" id="marker_uk" style="position:absolute;display:block;"><img src="images/marker.png"  /></a>
</article>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

    var pmap = document.getElementById('pmap'); 

    var marker_sl = document.getElementById('marker_sl');
    var marker_uk = document.getElementById('marker_uk');

        marker_sl.style.left = pmap.width * 70.5 / 100;
        marker_sl.style.top = pmap.height * 48 / 100;

        marker_uk.style.left = pmap.width * 44 / 100;
        marker_uk.style.top = pmap.height * 14.5 / 100;   

};
</script>
</html>
```

Solved code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

<body>
<article>
<img src="images/price_map.jpg" id="pmap" />
<a href="#" id="marker_sl" style="position:absolute;display:block;"><img src="images/marker.png"  /></a>
<a href="#" id="marker_uk" style="position:absolute;display:block;"><img src="images/marker.png"  /></a>
</article>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

    var pmap = document.getElementById('pmap'); 

    var marker_sl = document.getElementById('marker_sl');
    var marker_uk = document.getElementById('marker_uk');

        marker_sl.style.left = (pmap.width * 70.5 / 100)+"px";
        marker_sl.style.top = (pmap.height * 48 / 100)+"px";

        marker_uk.style.left = (pmap.width * 44 / 100)+"px";;
        marker_uk.style.top = (pmap.height * 14.5 / 100)+"px";   

};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser? Internet Explorer **does** change JavaScript behavior as well as rendering depending on the emulation/document mode in use (which can be driven by the DOCTYPE). However, I don't think other browsers do this.

Comment: @user113215 I've checked with chrome and firefox. Both gives the same out put. Haven't checked it on IE yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left` and `top` CSS properties require a unit, such as "px".

Comment: Well it is now solved :)
I've added (pmap.width * 70.5 / 100)+"px";

Comment: Thank You for pointing out that. Saved lot of effort and time. Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The document declaration shouldn't have any effect on the javascript. Post the html file, alternatively open up firebug and see what books you get running it with the document declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your response;
I've added all the code. Please take a look.